# Heroku application error although pushed and migrated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have pushed my application to heroku and run rake db:migrate with no problems then when i typed heroku open i got application error message and here is logs of heroku

```
2013-09-17T05:57:36.454255+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by darkbrotherhood.assassin@gmail.com
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "tickets" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"tickets"'::regclass
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"tickets"'::regclass
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1153:in `exec_no_cache'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:662:in `block in exec_query'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047530+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `exec_query'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1278:in `column_definitions'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:857:in `columns'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047727+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `yield'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:237:in `columns_hash'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:129:in `locking_enabled?'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation.rb:160:in `block in to_a'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/explain.rb:40:in `logging_query_plan'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation.rb:159:in `to_a'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.047874+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `all'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/ticket.rb:52:in `<class:Ticket>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/ticket.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048292+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.048853+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049100+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-09-17T05:57:38.049242+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-09-17T05:57:39.154755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-09-17T05:57:39.163867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-17T05:57:42.367168+00:00 heroku[run.8350]: Awaiting client
2013-09-17T05:57:42.387694+00:00 heroku[run.8350]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-09-17T05:57:43.822030+00:00 heroku[run.8350]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-17T05:57:57.126537+00:00 heroku[run.8350]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-17T05:57:57.148289+00:00 heroku[run.8350]: State changed from up to complete
2013-09-17T05:58:09.700142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=intense-river-8602.herokuapp.com fwd="197.163.97.240" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T05:58:10.967355+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-river-8602.herokuapp.com fwd="197.163.97.240" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T05:58:29.705467+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=intense-river-8602.herokuapp.com fwd="197.163.97.240" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-17T05:59:58.590498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=intense-river-8602.herokuapp.com fwd="197.163.97.240" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Presumably you have a `Ticket` model but no `tickets` table. Do you have a migration that is supposed to create that table or are you missing a set up step?

Comment: yes i have and during migrating to heroku i saw it was created

Comment: But the error appears to be happening while cranking up Rails to `db:migrate`. Anything interesting going on in your initializers?

Comment: i have tried local production everything works normally , just created a new ticket now , and it saved to my production.sqlite3

Comment: May I recommend that you switch to using PostgreSQL in your development env as well? Also, as mentioned, please post initializers and perhaps the migration that creates the tickets table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after changing `config.serve_static_assets = false` to be `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production.rb and then push to heroku again